# One-parameter subgroup

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups

I'm reading Alexander Kirillov's [book](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Ekirillov/liegroups/liegroups.pdf) about Lie groups, and at the beginning of chapter 3, he want to prove the existence and uniqueness of the one-parameter subgroup

[image]

The "usual" argument is
$\underset{h\to0}{\lim}\frac{e^{x+h}-e^x}{h}=
\underset{h\to0}{\lim}\frac{e^x e^h-e^x}{h}=
\underset{h\to0}{\lim}\frac{e^x(e^h-1)}{h}=e^x \phi(0)$

Where $\phi=\frac{de^x}{dx}$

If we will try to apply it to general Lie groups morphism $\gamma:\mathbb{K}\to G$ where $\mathbb{K}\in\{\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}\}$ and $G$ is a real\complex Lie group, then
$\gamma'(x)$ **is not** $\underset{h\to0}{\lim}\frac{\gamma(x+h)-\gamma(x)}{h}$ **but**
$\underset{h\to0}{\lim}\frac{\Phi(\gamma(x+h))-\Phi(\gamma(x))}{h}$, where $\Phi:U_x\to \mathbb{K}^{\dim(G)}$ is the chart of the "good" neighborhood $U_x$ of $x\in G$.

If $\gamma'(x)=\underset{h\to0}{\lim}\frac{\gamma(x+h)-\gamma(x)}{h}$ then of course $\gamma'(x)=\gamma(x)\gamma'(0)$ because $\gamma$ is a morphism of Lie groups, but it cannot be applyed to $\underset{h\to0}{\lim}\frac{\Phi(\gamma(x+h))-\Phi(\gamma(x))}{h}$.

Then what else can I do to see why $\gamma'(x)=\gamma(x)\gamma'(0)$?

Comment: Lie group (not "lie group") :)

Comment: @DietrichBurde Fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One parameter subgroup $\gamma$ is by defintion a smooth map $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow G$ such that for every $s,t$ we have:

$$\gamma(s+t)=\gamma(s)\gamma(t)$$
I.e.

$$\gamma(s+t)=L_{\gamma(s)}\gamma(t)$$

Fix $s$ in the above equation and diffrenriate using chain rule with respect to $t$ at $t=0$ to get:

$$\gamma'(s)=DL_{\gamma(s)}|_{\gamma(0)}\gamma'(0)$$